# How do I check if a string is valid JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json

In Python, is there a way to check if a string is valid JSON before trying to parse it?

For example working with things like the Facebook Graph API, sometimes it returns JSON, sometimes it could return an image file.

Comment: the api should set the content type

Comment: You can't specify what data is returned in the API call? I'm not familiar with the Facebook API but that sounds really odd.

Comment: I have done once, *but* with [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/474/write-a-json-validator/527#527) way

Comment: Most of the responses are json, but, if you call the profile photo it just returns the jpg

Comment: "Call the profile photo" endpoint? That should be documented as _returning an image_, and not "sometimes return JSON" (at least not for a 200 status code).

Answer (score 326, accepted):

You can try to do `json.loads()`, which will throw a `ValueError` if the string you pass can't be decoded as JSON.

In general, the "[Pythonic](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-pythonic)" philosophy for this kind of situation is called [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), for *Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission*.

Comment: I can see how that will work. Leads me to my next question. It throws a ValueError. What I want it to do at this point is return the offending string so I can do something else with it. So far, I've only gotten the error message and type.

Comment: What's wrong with just returning the string you passed to `loads` in the except clause?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, just a noob mistake on my part. It appears I just cant call file.read() twice. But I can set a variable and use it. And thats what I did.

Comment: just a note... json.loads('10') doesn't throw the ValueError and I'm sure '10' is not a valid json ...

Comment: Despite the fact that the spec says that a JSON text must be an array or object, most encoders and decoders (including Python's) will work with any JSON value at the "top," including numbers and strings. `10` is a valid JSON number value.

Comment: @wahrheit: If you want to detect that as an error, check whether the return value from `json.loads()` is a dictionary or list.

Comment: @JohnFlatness  is there anyway to check file type.. whether it is json or XML? In my case user will do input an "URL" which might consist json or xml data. so is there any way to check the type in Python?

Comment: digits can be decoded as json... but than you'll have an exception when will try retrieve some parameter (TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable)

Comment: EAFP :"This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements." Cue this-is-fine comic.

Comment: Unfortunately, {"a":1,"a":2} passes this test whereas it has duplicate property keys. Most of the parsers don't complain and usually consider the latest property .. However, there is definitely a problem.

Comment: @Myobis the tricky bit is that the relevant standards either don't say anything at all about duplicate keys or only say that they "SHOULD" be avoided, so it's not really invalid even though it may be problematic. Python does let you get at those duplicates if you use `object_pairs_hook`.

Comment: In current versions of Python 3, `json.loads()` throws a `JSONDecodeError`, which is (indeed) a subclass of `ValueError`, with some useful extra information. See [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/json/decoder.py#L20).

Comment: json.loads('{"position": NaN, "score": 0.3}') doesn't throw an error but my backend friends jsonlint.com both say it is not valid.

Comment: @bonobo Python's JSON support both emits and accepts non-standard infinity and NaN values for numbers. [The manual describes this and how to alter it if necessary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#infinite-and-nan-number-values), with the `parse_constant` argument.

Answer (score 227):

### Example Python script returns a boolean if a string is valid json:

```
import json

def is_json(myjson):
  try:
    json.loads(myjson)
  except ValueError as e:
    return False
  return True
```

Which prints:

```
print is_json("{}")                          #prints True
print is_json("{asdf}")                      #prints False
print is_json('{ "age":100}')                #prints True
print is_json("{'age':100 }")                #prints False
print is_json("{\"age\":100 }")              #prints True
print is_json('{"age":100 }')                #prints True
print is_json('{"foo":[5,6.8],"foo":"bar"}') #prints True
```

**Convert a JSON string to a Python dictionary:**

```
import json
mydict = json.loads('{"foo":"bar"}')
print(mydict['foo'])    #prints bar

mylist = json.loads("[5,6,7]")
print(mylist)
[5, 6, 7]
```

**Convert a python object to JSON string:**

```
foo = {}
foo['gummy'] = 'bear'
print(json.dumps(foo))           #prints {"gummy": "bear"}
```

If you want access to low-level parsing, don't roll your own, use an existing library: http://www.json.org/

Great tutorial on python JSON module:  https://pymotw.com/2/json/

### Is String JSON and show syntax errors and error messages:

```
sudo cpan JSON::XS
echo '{"foo":[5,6.8],"foo":"bar" bar}' > myjson.json
json_xs -t none < myjson.json
```

Prints:

```
, or } expected while parsing object/hash, at character offset 28 (before "bar}
at /usr/local/bin/json_xs line 183, <STDIN> line 1.
```

`json_xs` is capable of syntax checking, parsing, prittifying, encoding, decoding and more:

https://metacpan.org/pod/json_xs

Comment: Do you think we should `del json_object` once validated?

Comment: Why the hell isn't there a proper validation method? There should be a way to error check without killing canaries.

Comment: What I'm getting at is: Just because Python allows for OO doesn't mean it's okay to ignore the other parts. I should have the option of either A. letting the function fail and using exceptions (the OO/Python way), or B. calling a function that returns a value (success or error) instead of throwing an exception, and then having my function, in turn, return a sentinel value that indicates an error, so that errors bubble up the call stack and can be used as necessary (the procedural/C way). Just as C++ doesn't force you to use exceptions (you can use errno), Python shouldn't force it, either

Comment: @EricLeschinski but there isn't a halting problem here. The program clearly raises an exception if an error occurs while parsing JSON. Therefore, the program knows when JSON input is invalid. Therefore, it is 100% possible to have a function that checks whether the input is valid without having to use `try`. #StopCanaryAbuse

Answer (score 2):

I would say parsing it is the only way you can really entirely tell. Exception will be raised by python's `json.loads()` function (almost certainly) if not the correct format. However, the the purposes of your example you can probably just check the first couple of non-whitespace characters...

I'm not familiar with the JSON that facebook sends back, but most JSON strings from web apps will start with a open square `[` or curly `{` bracket. No images formats I know of start with those characters.

Conversely if you know what image formats might show up, you can check the start of the string for their signatures to identify images, and assume you have JSON if it's not an image.

Another simple hack to identify a graphic, rather than a text string, in the case you're looking for a graphic, is just to test for non-ASCII characters in the first couple of dozen characters of the string (assuming the JSON is ASCII).

Answer (score 1):

An effective, and reliable way to check for valid JSON. If the 'get' accessor does't throw an `AttributeError` then the JSON is valid.

```
import json

valid_json =  {'type': 'doc', 'version': 1, 'content': [{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'text': 'Request for widget', 'type': 'text'}]}]}
invalid_json = 'opo'

def check_json(p, attr):
    doc = json.loads(json.dumps(p))
    try:
        doc.get(attr) # we don't care if the value exists. Only that 'get()' is accessible
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

To use, we call the function and look for a key.

```
# Valid JSON
print(check_json(valid_json, 'type'))
```

Returns 'True'

```
# Invalid JSON / Key not found
print(check_json(invalid_json, 'type'))
```

Returns 'False'

Comment: `get()` returns None, not raises `AttributeError`. Did you mean to use `doc[attr]`? Or except ValueError instead?

Comment: If the object contains valid JSON then calling get, and the None that it would return is irrelevant. i.e. the fact that 'get()' is callable means that it is JSON.

If on the other hand 'get()' isn't found then it is an attribute error because we calling a non JSON object.

Comment: Feel free to run the code and see:  https://onecompiler.com/python/3yytpvfpr

Comment: "Fact that get is callable" - Well, no, that means it is a `dict()`, and that `json.loads` did not throw **ValueError / TypeError**. In other words, `json.loads` should be in the try body, [as answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20725965/2308683) ... `'opo'` is still "valid JSON" since plain strings are still JSON. Better example - https://onecompiler.com/python/3yywagm8h

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an generic, interesting solution to this problem:

```
class SafeInvocator(object):
    def __init__(self, module):
        self._module = module

    def _safe(self, func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                return None

        return inner

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        obj = getattr(self.module, item)
        return self._safe(obj) if hasattr(obj, '__call__') else obj
```

and you can use it like so:

```
safe_json = SafeInvocator(json)
text = "{'foo':'bar'}"
item = safe_json.loads(text)
if item:
    # do something
```

Comment: I think general solutions are good, but in this case, the `except` clause may hide any serious exception. Catching exceptions must be as restrictive as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also used `json.loads()` to check if a string is a valid JSON, however I also needed  to check if it is complex data structure or not. I did not want to save to the db a simple string or an integer for example...
These are also valid JSON, but sometimes must be filter as well:

- `"\"valid json\""`
- `"1"`
- `"3.14"`

My solution is here:

```py
def is_json(string: str, is_complex: bool = False) -> bool:
    """
    Return True if the given string is in valid JSON format, else return False.

    Example usage
    -------------
    >>> is_json("1")       # True because this is a valid JSON string
    True

    >>> is_json("1", True) # return False because this is a simple data structure (int)
    False

    :param string:
    :param is_complex: bool; If true also checked for complex data structure
    :return: bool
    """
    try:
        valid_json = json.loads(string)
        if is_complex and type(valid_json) in [int, str, float, bool]:
            return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

Much simple in try block. You can then validate if the body is a valid JSON

```
async def get_body(request: Request):
try:
    body = await request.json()
except:
    body = await request.body()
return body
```

Comment: At least check the status code and Content-Type headers