# Check if a string is not a deserialised json or list in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which can be of the form:

```
s1 = "Hello HAHA"
s2 = '["Hello HAHA"]'
s3 = "{Hello HAHA}"
```

I want to find out if the input string is like s1, s2 or s3. My motive is to sanitise this input and save it in `s1` format.

Basically I need to know if the input string is in `s1` form or not.

Solutions I have thought of:

1. `json.loads(s)` and catch exception to check if it is a json or not
2. Regex search to see if the input string has `{|}|[|]` in it in the starting and end position, and replace them.

What will be the most **pythonic** way to go about it?

Comment: IMHO, the most pythonic way would be to try parsing as JSON and catching the exception. [Python's exceptions are cheap and meant to be used extensively](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/).

Comment: Yo but that will just solve for `s3`, not `s2`. That is where the bigger problem is @jsfan

Comment: Correction: json.loads will work for s2 too and will thus solve problem :D

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`strip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). `s.strip('[]"{}')` will remove the unwanted characters at the ends of the string.

```
>>> unwanted = '[]"{}'

>>> 'Hello HAHA'.strip(unwanted)
'Hello HAHA'

>>> '["Hello HAHA"]'.strip(unwanted)
'Hello HAHA'

>>> '{Hello HAHA}'.strip(unwanted)
'Hello HAHA'
```

Comment: How is this answering the question? For example, not every string that begins with [ and ends with ] is a valid list after evaluation. Did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: @timgeb The question says there are 3 forms.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach for the JSON string is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508509/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-valid-json-in-python). I'd check for the list like this:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> def is_listliteral(x):
...     try:
...         return isinstance(literal_eval(x), list)
...     except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
...         return False
>>> is_listliteral('[')
False
>>> is_listliteral('[1,"2",{}]')
True
>>> is_listliteral('{}')
False
```

And I'm sure you can write the conditional statements to check for either JSON or list and then return `True` for the string check if both of those fail.

edit: There's a downside: this solution only works for nested lists if the objects inside can be evaluated by `literal_eval` (strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`).

```
>>> is_listliteral('[1,2,{1,2,3}]')
False
```

So it's not perfect. It might be good enough for your case. I don't know a better solution for now.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is the big takeaway here. I can use it to test for json as well. Any idea about what is more efficient though? `ujson.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()`? @timgeb

Comment: @ketanbhatt "I can use it to test for json as well." <- why would you? Any string that would be a valid python dictionary could be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

> Regex search to see if the input string has `{|}|[|]` in it in the starting and end position, and replace them.

```
re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', string)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'^[\[{"']+|['"}\]]+$', '', string)
```

This removes one or more non-word characters exists at the start or at the end.

Comment: @PeterWood `\W` should alo match quotes.