# JSON string parser without literals

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

How to check if a string like this `{:[{},{}]}`, without any literals, can be represented as a JSON object or not?

The input comes with the following constraints:
1. A JSON object should start with '{' and ends with a '}'.
2. The key and value should be separated by a ':'.
3. A ',' suggests an additional JSON property.
4. An array only consists of JSON objects. It cannot contain a "key":"value" pair by itself.

And it is to be intrepreted like this:

```
{
"Key": [{
"Key": "Value"
}, {
"Key": "Value"
}]
}
```

Comment: `{}` is probably a literal, too :-)

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if your string is valid JSON (that would parse to an object)?

Comment: I meant without anything like `'key'`, `'value`, `'abc'`, `'123'` etc.

Comment: Yeah! just checking if it is a valid JSON

Comment: What's wrong with just running it through a JSON parser ?

Comment: Without any keys, and resulting in an object, can there be any other JSON than `{}`? (ignoring whitespace)

Comment: Using `json.loads('{:[{},{}]}')` in a `try-except` block is giving wrong answer for this.

Comment: I came across this question, where this input comes with the following constraints:
1. A JSON object should start with '{' and ends with a '}'.
2. The key and value should be separated by a ':'.
3. A ',' suggests an additional JSON property.
4. An array only consists of JSON objects. It cannot contain a "key":"value" pair by itself.

Comment: What is the wrong answer? looks invalid to me (might be mistaken), does the parser accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is valid JSON in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508509/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-valid-json-in-python)

Comment: What is "the wrong answer"? For the record, it is not valid JSON. See the railroad diagrams here: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax spec for JSON [can be found here](http://www.json.org/).

It indicates that the `[{},{}]` is legal, because `[]` has to contain 0 or more elements separated by `,`, and `{}` is a legal element. However, the first part of your example is NOT valid - the `:` must have a string in front of it. While it is legal for it to be an empty string, it's not legal for it to be null, and the interpretation of a totally missing element is ambiguous.

So. `{"":[{},{}]}` is legal, but `{:[{},{}]}` is not.