# How to compare a character at a specific location in a string to identify the processing path

Tags: json, xml, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to identify if the first character in a .txt/string is either a "{" or a "<". Depending on which will determine how the .txt is handled.

I'm working with two systems where one takes xml and the other takes json. So, as a file comes from one system it's converted and sent to the other. I've worked out the conversion for the files if they have the correct file extension but now I'm needing to be able to identify if a file is json or xml based off the content of a .txt file. I don't know why this would occur but was asked to include it.

Best way, as far as I can tell, is based off the first character within the file. If it's "<" than it is xml, if it's "{" than it's json. I'm not aware of a character that is only in json or only in xml that I can search through and identify that way.

The code below the # txt to xml and json is searching the whole file for the string which can give false positives which is why I'm trying to look at just the first character.

```py
start_path = 'fileLocation'
for path,dirs,files in os.walk(start_path):
    for fileName in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(path,fileName)

        # xml2json
        if re.match('.*\.xml',fileName):
            with open(filePath) as x:
                xStr = x.read()
            jStr = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xStr), indent=4)
            with open("jsonOutput.json", 'w') as j:
                j.write(jStr)

        # json2xml
        elif re.match('.*\.json',fileName):
            with open(filePath) as j:
                jStr = j.read()
            xStr = xmltodict.unparse(json.loads(jStr), pretty=True)
            with open('xmlOutput.xml', 'w') as x:
                x.write(xStr)

        # **Where I'm Having Trouble**
        # txt to xml and json
        elif re.match('.*\.txt',fileName):
            with open(filePath) as t:
                tStr = t.read()
                if 'xml' in tStr:
                    with open('xmlOutput.xml', 'w') as x:
                        x.write(tStr)
                elif '{' in tStr:
                    with open('jsonOutput.xml', 'w') as j:
                        j.write(tStr)
```

The ideal solution would replace the 'xml' and '{' full txt search with '<' and '{' checking the first character.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you.

Comment: You can try reading `json` in a `try except` and if that fails just read it as a `csv`. `json.loads()` will through a `ValueError` if it is invalid json. If it throws that then you know it is not `json`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508552/8150685

Comment: If you don't want to do it that way then the best alternative is either to use a simple string character match (if it is always the first character) or a `regex` to check if it is `json`. Though I would probably go the `try except` route.

Comment: That is a good solution, I forgot about the whole "if it fails process it this way" solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found a solution using readline(). This reads only the first line and if '{' is found it will process as a json, if there's an '<' it will process as xml. Thanks everyone for the help.

```
# unk to json & xml
        else:
            with open(filePath) as u:
                fLine = u.readline() #This is only reading the first line.
                uStr = u.read()
            if '<' in fLine:
                time = strftime('%Y%b%d %H%M', gmtime())
                fName = fileName + ' ' + time + ".xml"
                with open(fName, 'w') as x:
                    x.write(uStr)
            elif '{' in fLine:
                time = strftime('%Y%b%d %H%M', gmtime())
                fName = fileName + ' ' + time + ".json"
                with open(fName, 'w') as j:
                    j.write(uStr)
```