# Django - Access Json

Tags: json, django

I have json like this below

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "interviewer": "hengtw1",
    "incidenttwg1": {
        "id": 5,
        "child_occupation": [
            6
        ],
    },
}
```

How can i access ***child_occupation array***. All i tried is `incidenttwg1['child_occupation']` or `['incidenttwg1']['child_occupation']`. Anyway its still doesn't work.

Any Help?? Thanks....

Comment: Are you trying to access this Json in a Django view? You have to convert the json to a python dictionary first using json.loads() and then access it as a python dictionary

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508509/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-valid-json-in-python) if your string is valid json in python
and
refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to know more about json encoder and decoder

```
 import json
 # Decoding json
 data = json.loads({"id": 1,"interviewer": "hengtw1","incidenttwg1": {"id": 5,"child_occupation": [6]}})
 print(data["incidenttwg1"]["child_occupation"]) 
 # this will print [6] (list)
 print(data["incidenttwg1"]["child_occupation"][0])
 # this will print 6 (list item)
```